# backstopjs missmatch errors issue

Tags: backstop.js

I am new to backstopjs, I was able to download it globally. My project directory structure looks like the following. I set up instance of backstopjs in my tests/backstopjs directory with backstop init :

[image: backstop installed in tests/backstopjs]

The page I want to reference is index.html in my app directory:

[image: index file location]

My scenarios in the backstop.js file are the following:

```
"scenarios": [
    {
      "label": "My index test",
      "url": "~/app/index.html",
      "referenceUrl": "",
      "readyEvent": "",
      "readySelector": "",
      "delay": 0,
      "hideSelectors": [],
      "removeSelectors": [],
      "hoverSelector": "",
      "clickSelector": "",
      "postInteractionWait": "",
      "selectors": [
        ".list-content"
      ],
      "selectorExpansion": true,
      "misMatchThreshold" : 0.1,
      "requireSameDimensions": true
    }
  ],
```

I am trying to taget the list-content class on my index.html page.

The error I am getting is:

```
report | *** Mismatch errors found ***
      COMMAND | Command `report` ended with an error after [0.089s]
      COMMAND | Command `test` ended with an error after [32.08s]
```

And the report page result:

[image: backstopjs result page]

Is my url path completely wrong, or is it something else I have missed?

Comment: On one of the sample projects I ran has the same project structure and content as the one on https://css-tricks.com/automating-css-regression-testing/ site, but using the backstop test instead and executing the command on the root. The scenarios code is also the same as suggested on that page. So the url path is the same as suggested on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my url path was wrong, I tried it out on a simpler project setup.
But from the screen dumps above, can someone suggest the proper relative path for my url setting from my tests/backstopjs folder where the backstop.json exits to my app where the index.html file exists?